# return an array from database

Tags: php, sql

I have a problem using str_ireplace with an array returned from a database table.
I want to use a table to hold bad words that will be filtered from a chat.

```
$msg = "some user input, with a few bad words."; //(not putting bad words here, just an example)
$words = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblBadWords")->result_array(); 
$replacement = "@#$@#";   
$msg = str_ireplace($words, $replacement, $msg);  //<--nothing happens

$word = str_ireplace($words[0], $replacement, $msg);  //<--nothing happens

$word = str_ireplace($words[1], $replacement, $msg);  //<--filters first word in table only
```

What am I doing wrong? Please note I am new to php database coding.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, from that code, $words will be an array, each element representing one line of the SQL result. If you have a table like that:

```
    id |         badword
   ----|--------------------------
    1  |         kangaroo
    2  |         bad-kangaroo
    3  |         very-bad-kangaroo
```

There will be three lines in your PHP array. There are surely a lot of solutions to this, but as a simple solution, you could just iterate over the array like that:

```
foreach ($words as $lineInMyBadWordTable) {
    $msg = str_ireplace($lineInMyBadWordTable['badword'], $replacement, $msg);
}
```

So, basically, if you access $words[0] or $words[n], you'll access one row of the result set which has been returned by the database management system. $words[0] will most likely be a result as well, representing the complete row of the record. For further reference, please consult the PHP documentation of str_ireplace:

[http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php]

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to dig into your array. Currently, your query returns something like the following:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 1
                [BadWord] => bad
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 2
                [BadWord] => Input
            )
    )
```

This comes from my sample assuming a table:

```
ID    |  BadWord
---------|-----------
1        | bad
2        | Input
```

You can achieve digging in by going for each Array within the array, get the array block (i.e. $badword[1] where $badword[0] is your ID field;  I found the need to specify the table heading as that is how my print_r showed the array).

```
foreach($words as $badword){
        $replacethese = $badword['BadWord'];
        $msg = str_ireplace($replacethese, $replacement, $msg);
    }
```

Now you can do whatever with the $msg. Mine came out as  such:

```
some user @#$@#, with a few @#$@# words.
```